# Swift Protocol Declaration: Argument Labels?

Tags: swift, function, syntax, protocols

Can or are Function Argument Labels (as opposed to Function Parameter Names) ever told/declared within a Protocol?

Or is it always done in the adopting type and/or extensions?

Comment: eggzachery! Thank you!

Comment: I've made my comment into an answer and added explanations.

Comment: Your answer is fantastic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a protocol, you have to declare the parameters for your functions. This is when you choose if/how many parameters your functions have, not later.

---

A protocol is like a contract. The binding parts are already decided before you use them.

When an object conforms to a protocol, it has to use its functions as you declared them, there's no option to add/change/remove parameters.

With a protocol like this, for example:

```
protocol Juggling {

    func juggle(object: String, number: Int)

    func launch(object: String, howMany number: Int)

}
```

the object conforming to the protocol have to use the functions as they're declared:

```
struct Juggler: Juggling {

    let name: String

    func juggle(object: String, number: Int) {
        print("Juggling \(number) x \(object)")
    }

    func launch(object: String, howMany number: Int) {
        print("Launching \(number) x \(object)")
    }

}
```

And on the caller side you have to also you them as they are declared:

```
let joe = Juggler(name: "Joe")
joe.launch(object: "baton", howMany: 2)
joe.juggle(object: "ball", number: 5)
```

You can't have, for example, the `launch` method with "number" instead of "howMany" on the caller side, it wouldn't conform to the protocol anymore.

It's the same rules when using protocol extensions:

```
protocol Juggling {

    func juggle(object: String, number: Int)

    func launch(object: String, howMany number: Int)

}

extension Juggling {

    func juggle(object: String, number: Int) {
        print("Juggling \(number) x \(object)")
    }

    func launch(object: String, howMany number: Int) {
        print("Launching \(number) x \(object)")
    }

}

struct Juggler: Juggling {

    let name: String

}

let joe = Juggler(name: "Joe")
joe.launch(object: "baton", howMany: 2)
joe.juggle(object: "ball", number: 5)
```

For example if you try to use

```
joe.launch(object: "baton", number: 2)
```

instead of

```
joe.launch(object: "baton", howMany: 2)
```

on the caller side, Xcode will actually show a fix-it and a suggestion to replace the parameter name.